# Helping with a book?

Tags: meaning, phrases, american-english

I have been reading a book about programming and i came across a sentence which says:

> but if you don’t
>   reuse some of what you’re doing, you’ll eventually
>   wear your fingers down to painful stubs
>   through overtyping.

And i don't get this part: What does "Painful Stubs" mean?

Thanks.

Comment: The pressure caused by over-typing will eventually reduce your finger size. Like a cigarette stub.

Comment: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-E4NypR-jSOo/UfsxRgaQYhI/AAAAAAAABL8/F5WrQepD61I/s1600/FingerNail_Tattoo_3342.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Stub](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stub)***.

> noun: a truncated or unusually short thing:

The text is humorously suggesting that if you unnecessarily repeat typing things that you have typed before, you will be typing so much that your fingers will be worn down to short stubs.

To give you some visual aid, babies fingers are often described as "[stubby](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stubby?q=stubby)".

[image]